# Qt input dialog - enter value without closing

Tags: c++, qt

I have QtInputDialog and I dont like it that, when i press enter it closes.

I would like to type value and confirm it  by pressing enter on keyboard. After that line edit resets and i can type another value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog initialization:

```
void MainWindow::on_button1_clicked() {
  dialog = new QInputDialog();
  dialog->installEventFilter(this);
  dialog->show();
}
```

Event filter:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e) {
  if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    if (static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e)->matches(QKeySequence::InsertParagraphSeparator)) {
      qDebug() << dialog->textValue(); //use this value as you wish
      dialog->setTextValue(QString());
      return true; //block this event
    }
  }
  return false; 
}
```

Note that the dialog still can be closed using mouse click on "OK".